# Change position of last image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, setinterval

**The code:**

```
function showLetter() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var letter = imgsArray[random()];
        var top = random();
        var left = random();
        $("div").append("<img src='imgs/" + letter + ".png'>");
        $("div").last().css({"position": "absolute", "top": top + "px", "left": left + "px"});
    }, 1000);
}
```

In each position of the array `imgsArray`, I have the name of an image.

**What I want to do**:
Add an image every 1000 ms, giving it a random position on the screen. (If it's possible to prevent overlapping, that'd be great, but I think that has already been answered).

**What it does**:
Every 1000 ms, it adds a new image of a letter, and gives the same properties to all images so they all end up horizontally aligned **:)**

I really don't understand why this is happening. With `$("div").last().css()`, am I not choosing the last image added to the div and changing **only** its properties?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`$("div").last()` gives you the last item in the `` `$("div") `` jquery object.  There are no images in that jQuery object.

Perhaps what you want is:

```
$("div img").last()
```

But, that is quite inefficient.  If you just want to operate on the newly created image object, then you can just operate on it directly:

```
function showLetter() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var letter = imgsArray[random()];
        var top = random();
        var left = random();
        var img = $("<img src='imgs/" + letter + ".png'>");
        img.css({"position": "absolute", "top": top + "px", "left": left + "px"});
        $("div").append(img);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, what you said works, thanks a lot @jfriend00.
But I don't understand how is it that there are not images in the div. I append one in the previous line. Can you explain? :)

Comment: @user2484181 - You are only selecting the parent `div` and operating only on it which is obviously not what you want.  That doesn't select the children `img` objects.  FYI, I added a better way to do this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider something like this:

```
var div = $('<div/>').css({position:'absolute'....}).appendTo('body');
var img = $('<img/>', {src:'imgs/' + letter + '.png'}).appendTo(div);
```

This will add new <div> containing an image to <body>.